# Cannot move std::any

Tags: c++, c++17, move, move-semantics, stdany

The following code

```
using vptr = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>;
auto m = std::unordered_map<int, std::any>{};
m.try_emplace(0, move(vptr{}));
```

Fails to compile, complaining about using of deleted copy constructor of `unique_ptr`. After replacing `std::any` with `vptr` in template argument this code compiles, so the issue is clearly with `any`

How can I force `std::any` to be moved instead of copied?

Comment: Note that you don't need to do `move(vptr{})`, `vptr{}` is already an rvalue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not moving `std::any`, it's that `std::any` itself does not support move-only types (`std::unique_ptr` for example)

as per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any/any)

```
template< class ValueType >
any( ValueType&& value );
```

> Constructs an object with initial content an object of type `std::decay_t< ValueType>`, direct-initialized from `std::forward< ValueType>(value)`. **If `std::is_copy_constructible< std::decay_t< ValueType>>::value` is `false`, the program is ill-formed**

You can check that is_copy_constructible ... is false with a static_assert, see on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e25e04b47ea1d15)

Easiest workaround I can think of is to use shared_ptr instead and still call the std::move.