# Move only type adapting std::any with dummy copy constructor is safe?

Tags: c++, c++17, move, stdany

I'd like to initialize `std::any` with a move only type variable. I found [Cannot move std::any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369214/cannot-move-stdany/56369931#56369931).

### Compile error case

Before I use shared_ptr workaround from the linked answer, I tested the following code:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

struct move_only {
    move_only() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    move_only(move_only const&) = delete;
    move_only(move_only &&) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    move_only m;
    std::any a(std::move(m)); // error. copy constructor is required
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/h6HOSdgOnQYg4a6K

The code above outputs compile error because of `move_only` doesn't have copy constructor.

### Add copy constructor for test

I added copy constructor for test.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

struct move_only {
    move_only() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    move_only(move_only const&) {
        // not called
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    move_only(move_only &&) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    move_only m;
    std::any a(std::move(m)); // success but copy constructor is not called
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/kxEnIslmVnJNRSn6

Then compile successfully finished as I expected. And I got interesting output.

```
move_only::move_only()
move_only::move_only(move_only &&)
```

It seems that the copy constructor isn't called. It is surprising for me.

And I come up with the following wrapper approach.

### Add dummy copy constructor wrapper

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

struct move_only {
    move_only() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    move_only(move_only const&) = delete;
    move_only(move_only &&) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct wrapped_move_only : move_only {
    wrapped_move_only(move_only&& m):move_only(std::move(m)) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    wrapped_move_only(wrapped_move_only const&) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
        assert(false);
    }
    wrapped_move_only(wrapped_move_only &&) = default;

};

int main() {
    move_only m;
    wrapped_move_only wmo(std::move(m));
    std::any a(std::move(wmo));
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/EDhq3KPWKP9fCA9v

The copy constructor of move_only is deleted. The class wapped_move_only inherits move_only and added copy constructor.

It successfully compiled and I got the following result.

```
move_only::move_only()
move_only::move_only(move_only &&)
wrapped_move_only::wrapped_move_only(move_only &&)
move_only::move_only(move_only &&)
```

It seems that I initialized std::any with move only type using the wrapper that provides dummy copy constructor. It is more efficient to use shared_ptr if the goal is just initialize std::any with move only type. It is expected behavior for me.

As long as I do move operation only for `std::any` once `move_only` is moved to `std::any`, is this code safe?
If `std::any` is copied, then assetion failed due to copy constructor of wrapped_move_only is called. I want to know move only case's safety.

I am also not sure why `std::any`'s target requires copy constructor but it is not called.

### templatized

If it is safe, I can improve this approach using template. The template `add_dummy_copy_constructor` is a kind of adaptor.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <any>

struct move_only {
    move_only() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    move_only(move_only const&) = delete;
    move_only(move_only &&) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct add_dummy_copy_constructor : T {
    add_dummy_copy_constructor(T&& t):T(std::move(t)) {}
    add_dummy_copy_constructor(add_dummy_copy_constructor const&) {
        assert(false);
    }
    add_dummy_copy_constructor(add_dummy_copy_constructor &&) = default;
};

int main() {
    move_only m;
    std::any a(add_dummy_copy_constructor(std::move(m)));
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/guEWPIrK9wiJ3BgW

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am also not sure why `std::any`'s target requires copy constructor but it is not called.

The design of `std::any` is to be one concrete type that can hold *any* copyable type. When you copy a `std::any`, you copy whatever it is it's holding underneath

The `std::any` needs to know *how* to copy the underlying object regardless of if it is ever actually going to be copied (how would it know whether or not this happens?). So it must be a compile error if the underlying type isn't copy-constructible.

However, when we're constructing the `std::any` itself, at that point we know the concrete object we're constructing from. And if that concrete object happens to be an rvalue, then we can just move-construct `std::any`'s underlying object from the constructor parameter rather than copy-constructing. It's a free win there.

None of your code actually copies a `std::any`, so none of it would invoke `std::any`'s copy constructor which would invoke the underlying types copy constructor.

---

A similar thing happens with `std::function` and maybe it would be more obvious what the difference here is. When I construct a `std::function<void()>`, there is the static requirement that the object be invokable with no arguments. It is a compile error if it is not invokabe.

But simply constructing the `std::function<void()>` will not actually invoke the underlying function - those are separate operations. You wouldn't expect this assertion to trigger:

```
std::function<void()> f = []{ assert(false); }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. I understand why. When I read your answer at first, I thought that we could `std::any`'s copy constructor conditionally enable/disable depends on actual type but I realized that `std::any` is type erased type. The actual type is decided at run time. `std::any` provides copy constructor is reasonable choice. So the actual type need to have copy constructor.